# Как получить NMEA строку под win8 (C++ Win8 location Api)

Tags: геолокация, windows-8, c++

Подскажите, куском кода, как получить NMEA строку от gps приемника, стоящего на борту устройства под Win8? На msdn уже читал про Location Api, но там написано довольно мутно. Если под C# все понятно, то для C++ начинаются какие-то пляски с бубном.